# Typo Error:property data missing in type in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to create interface in interface.ts. data is an array of object inside the Column. Below is my interface code:

```js
export class User {
result: boolean;
messages: string;
Column=[];
data=[];
}
export class Column {  
name:string;
category:boolean;
count:number;
}

export class data {
name:string;
category:string;
}
```

below is the code used in service.

```js
getData(): Promise<User> {
return Promise.resolve(
{ result: true, messages: 'Maria','Column':[{
name:'ramu',category:'c',count:4, "data":[{"name":"",      "category":""
    }]
}]
}
);
}
```

But i got the type error. i have attached the screen shot please check. and below is the error screen- shot.
[Code URL Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-service-typechecking?file=app%2FDataService.service.ts)

[image]

Comment: In your getData code, the "data" is inside the Column property value, instead of being at the same level

Comment: @Ramu, please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-service-typechecking-fkmi6d-new-promise-xnfn8k?file=app/DataService.service.ts

Comment: hrdkisback, Exact answer. Please upload as answer

Comment: @Ramu You should accept an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
  getData(): Promise<User> {
return Promise.resolve(
{ result: true, messages: 'Maria',
  'Column':[{   name:'ramu',category:'c',count:4}], 
 "data":[{ "name":"", "category":"" }]
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from './interface';
import { Column } from './interface';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  userCookie: any;
  loginAlertMessage: string;
  constructor(private http: Http
  ) {
  }



  getData(): Promise<User> {
    return Promise.resolve(
      {
        result: true, messages: 'Maria',
        'Column': [{ name: 'ramu', category: 'c', count: 4 }],
        "data": [{ "name": "", "category": "" }]
      });
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-service-typechecking-ctfzwv?file=app%2FDataService.service.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this **interface.ts**

```
export class User {
  result: boolean;
  messages: string;
  Column=[];
}
export class Column {  
  name:string;
  category:boolean;
  count:number;
  data=[]; // data should be here in Column class
}
export class data {
  name:string;
  category:string;
}
```

**DataService**

```
getData(): Promise<User> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data);
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-service-typechecking-fkmi6d-new-promise-xnfn8k?file=app/DataService.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers here are valid.

In my opinion however you should just "type assert" the object to the Type you require (providing that the data is in the correct format to that which you require.)...

```
getData(): Promise<User> {
    return Promise.resolve(
      {
        result: true, messages: 'Maria',
        'Column': [{ name: 'ramu', category: 'c', count: 4 }],
        "data": [{ "name": "", "category": "" }]
      } as User);
  }
```

i.e. adding `as User` at the end of the object.